# Split string in c# and getting the right string

Tags: c#

I want to split this `String.`

```
text1:text2
```

My code:

```
string[] split = line.Split(':');
Console.WriteLine(split[0])
```

Output:

```
text1
```

How can I get "text2" ?

Comment: Look up array access https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_arrays.htm

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_indexers.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close:

The results are 0 based, so the first string starts at 0 which is why `split[0]` returns `text1`.

So to get the second element `text2` just use `split[1]` .

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the second element of the array: `split[1]`